# Textbox inside Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, custom-controls

Can someone please post a code in c# to create a Textbox inside a datagridview and which should have events like text_changed, enter , keydown events . i Have created a customcontrol datagridview for this as it will be used multiple times but dont know how to declare a textbox inside it .

```
  public partial class CustomControl1 : DataGridView
    {
        public CustomControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The `DataGridView` already creates a `TextBox` control when you edit a cell so it already has all those events. Are you just trying to access those events of that editing control?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , yes it does but i want to do specific task when the control enters , we types inside the cell and handle cetain key events .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGridView` already creates a control for the purpose of editing a cell in most cases. There are no controls in the grid by default, which makes performance better, and a cell entering edit mode is literally a control being created and embedded in the cell. The type of the control depends on the type of the cell, which generally depends on the type of the column. For most data, the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` is the default, so every editing control will be a `TextBox`.

When a cell enters edit mode, the `DataGridView` raises the `EditingControlShowing` event. You can access the editing control there and treat it like you would any other control, including handling its events. It's important that you detach any event handlers you added, which you can do in the `CellEndEdit` event handler. Here's an example of handling the `TextChanged` event of the editing control:

```cs
private TextBox editingControl;

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    editingControl = (TextBox)e.Control;
    editingControl.TextChanged += EditingControl_TextChanged;
}

private void EditingControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (editingControl != null)
    {
        editingControl.TextChanged -= EditingControl_TextChanged;
        editingControl = null;
    }
}
```